# Populating a calendar with PHP foreach code

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins

I am using the following jQuery calendar: https://github.com/MrHus/jquery-monthly-ical/tree/

Following the documentation, it tells me that dates should be entered like this:

```
eventdates: [{"date": "2009-03-21", "title": "My birthday", "desc": "Its my birthday!"},
             {"date": "yyyy-01-01", "title": "New Year", "desc": "Its a new year!"},
             {"date": "2009-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
             {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
             {"date": "2010-09-01", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention."}, 
             {"date": "2010-09-02", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention day two."}, 
             {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "Towl", "desc": "Dont forget to bring a towl."}    
            ]
```

However, I'd like to populate the above arrays with PHP variables, with a foreach statement. I've got this, however it doesn't work, no errors, no warnings, but the event is not displayed:

```
        <?php
        foreach($events as $event)
        {
        ?>
            eventdates: [{"date": "<?php date('Y/m/d') ?>", "title": "<?php $event->title ?>", "desc": "<a href="<?php  echo SITE_URL ?>/index.php/events/get_event?id=<?php $event->id ?>">Details/Signups</a>"},]
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

This is the previous code outside of calendar, and inside a table I had, and it works:

```
<?php
if(!$events)
{
    echo 'No Upcoming Events';
}
else
{
    ?>
<center>
    <table border="1px" width="80%">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%"><b>Date:</b></td>
            <td width="60%"><b>Event:</b></td>
            <td><b>Details/Signups</b></td>
        </tr>
            <?php
            foreach($events as $event)
            {
                if($event->active == '2')
                {
                    continue;
                }
        echo '<tr><td>'.date('n/j/Y', strtotime($event->date)).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$event->title.'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.SITE_URL.'/index.php/events/get_event?id='.$event->id.'">Details/Signups</a></td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </table>
</center>
    <?php
}
?>
```

The code is inside a .tpl file, which is shown via .class.php file. Inside of it, are all of the queries to run necessary variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$dates = array();

// build an array with that data
foreach($events as $event)
  $dates[] = (object)array(
     'date'  => date('Y/m/d'),
     'title' => $event->title,
     'desc'  => sprintf('<a href="%s/index.php/events/get_event?id=%s">Details/Signups</a>', SITE_URL, $event->id),
  );

?>

eventdates:

<?php print json_encode($dates); // print it as a json string ?>
```

Comment: It is showing the calendar, but it still does not display the events.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Qc8GByBE. I've tried your suggestion first: `'date'  => date('Y/m/d')` then changed it back to my version to see whether it will work.

Comment: It works, but for some odd reason, the title says null, and the event is displayed on today's date. Any ideas?

Comment: I missed a t off `$event`, my mistake, however it still displays on today's date...

Comment: If you want display the event date and not the current date, maybe you should do `date('Y-m-d', $event->date)` assuming that an event object has a timestamp as a `date` property (integer)

Comment: Great, thank you. Final question, how would I go about adding past events into the same calendar? They seem to be identified as `foreach($history as $event)`. Is anything like `foreach($a && $b as $c)` possible?

Comment: no, but you can do `foreach(array_merge($history, $events) as $event)...`

Comment: It made the calendar disappear. I replaced the `foreach($events as $event)` with your above code. I also tried `array_combine`.

Comment: It prints out an Array for `$events` but it returns empty for `$history`. This is what I get if I do `print_f($events)`: http://pastebin.com/ZysSbGv8. Although, again, a table displays the data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If I change `$events` to `$history`, it works.

Comment: You said you want to add past events to this calendar. You need to get those events from somehere right? Like the databse. Where did you get the current events from?

Comment: Yeah, I get what you mean now, however the `$history` variable works, because it parses information into a table identical to the one for `$events`. The `$events` variable is gained like this: http://pastebin.com/UznZZfDr

Comment: I think it's only a single array for some odd reason :| http://pastebin.com/3z9cDpXJ

Comment: I have just noted a confusing encounter. I have three events currently in the DB, two future events and one past event. I did what you suggested, however it didn't display past events. When I did `foreach($history + $events as $event)` it displayed the past event and ONE future event.

Comment: Because both have the same indexes and get overwritten by `+`. But that shouldn't happen with array_merge. Try with `array_merge(array_valyes($history), array_values($events))`

Comment: Just added another event, and to confirm, its showing only two events, regardless whether they're past or upcoming. Maybe the `+` is adding the variables together?

Edit:// Just seen your reply, going to give it a go.

Comment: I get the following errors when I upload this online, and I can't figure out what's the problem. The bizarre thing is it works on my localhost based server. I've also included the array `var_dump`: http://pastebin.com/Csp6WwJp