# Foreach issue with empty variables

Tags: php

I'd like to refer back to my original question: [Populating a calendar with PHP foreach code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798794/populating-a-calendar-with-php-foreach-code)

When working on a localhost server, the script works, however when uploaded online, the calendar does not appear, and Chrome gives me the following errors:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  array_values() [<a href='function.array-values'>function.array-values</a>]: The argument should be an array in <b>/home/flyeurov/public_html/lib/skins/flyeuro/events/events_index.tpl</b> on line <b>30</b>
<b>Warning</b>:  array_merge() [<a href='function.array-merge'>function.array-merge</a>]: Argument #2 is not an array in <b>/home/flyeurov/public_html/lib/skins/flyeuro/events/events_index.tpl</b> on line <b>30</b>
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/flyeurov/public_html/lib/skins/flyeuro/events/events_index.tpl</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
```

I have discovered that this is happening when I have no events happening in the past = `$history` therefore empty, or events planned for the future = `$events` empty.

```
foreach(array_merge(array_values($history), array_values($events)) as $event)
```

But my system is bound sometimes not to have any events planned, hence empty `$event`, so my question is, how can I bypass the foreach to display the calendar anyway with one or the other empty variable?

Comment: just add into merge another argument: `new array()`

Comment: if there are no events in the past, $history should be an **empty array** in the first place, not an **empty variable**. Initialize your variables properly and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!empty($history) || !empty($events)){
   foreach(array_merge(array_values($history), array_values($events)) as $event){...}
}
```

In your case This will be a better solution(Removed the if condition) :

```
$history = (!empty($history))?$history:array();
$events = (!empty($events))?$events:array();
foreach(array_merge(array_values($history), array_values($events)) as $event){...}
```

Comment: The calendar has disappeared now.

Comment: what exactly are you doing in side the foreach loop ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0f5sipJu - the result should be that the calendar should appear even if the variables are empty, but they have events currently in, and still don't appear. I must have messed something up in that code. Chrome is throwing an `Syntax Error: unexpected token: [` on `eventdates`.

Answer (score 0):

if (!empty($array)) {
...
}

This will check, before foreach.